# How to convince python stream objects to return true from isatty()?

Tags: python

Usually `isatty()` tells you if a stream is a TTY and is the common way to determine if the stdout or stderr is a console.

The problem is that when you run a script under a IDE the output is redirected so istty will return False or will not even be defined.

I want to add this attribute to the `sys.stdout` or even `sys.__stdout__` in order to change the behaviour of the library that was checkign for tty.

Still I would like to do this without having to replace the object itself with a proxy, if possible.

```
# some logic...
setattr(sys.stdout, 'isatty', True)
>> AttributeError: 'file' object attribute 'isatty' is read-only
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a proxy object. No solution that I can think of is easier than that.

```
class PseudoTTY(object):
    def __init__(self, underlying):
        self.__underlying = underlying
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.__underlying, name)
    def isatty(self):
        return True

sys.stdin = PseudoTTY(sys.stdin)
```

(The other solution would involve [ptys](http://docs.python.org/library/pty.html).)

Comment: This is very useful when using this for PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Tiny addition to @Fred Foo's comment. I used it and got:

```
AttributeError: 'OutputManager' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

So I made this tiny change and now it works.

```
class PseudoTTY(object):
    def __init__(self, underlying):
        underlying.encoding = 'cp437'
        self.__underlying = underlying
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.__underlying, name)
    def isatty(self):
        return True

sys.stdout = PseudoTTY(sys.stdout)
```