# Keras progress bar prints new lines instead of updating bar

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting this error on every place I try except for the Jupyter Notebook: the Python console, PyCharm, using tf.keras, using keras I installed, ect.
I have python 3.7.2 and my tensorflow is up to date.

I created a simple model for the MNIST dataset through Keras, and when I am trying to train with `verbose=1` I am getting new lines instead of the expected progress bar updating:

```
3808/60000 [>.............................] - ETA: 1:00 - loss: 0.9823 - acc: 0
3872/60000 [>.............................] - ETA: 1:00 - loss: 0.9753 - acc: 0
3936/60000 [>.............................] - ETA: 1:00 - loss: 0.9652 - acc: 0
4000/60000 [=>............................] - ETA: 1:00 - loss: 0.9544 - acc: 0
4064/60000 [=>............................] - ETA: 59s - loss: 0.9468 - acc: 0.
4128/60000 [=>............................] - ETA: 59s - loss: 0.9376 - acc: 0.
4192/60000 [=>............................] - ETA: 59s - loss: 0.9290 - acc: 0.
4256/60000 [=>............................] - ETA: 59s - loss: 0.9213 - acc: 0.
```

Any clue?

P.S. The accuracies aren't 0, it's not a part of this problem. I also made sure that `tqdm` loading bars work for me.
Here is the code if that's relevant: https://gist.github.com/omer54321/bde99aa48794a4221fd308a2c55a33dc

Comment: Funny, because works perfectly in Spyder 3.3.1 using Python 3.6.6 Qt 5.11.2 PyQt 5.11.3. ||    60000/60000 [==============================] - 31s 515us/step - loss: 0.1939 - acc: 0.9413

Comment: Please check: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5906

Comment: @Rubens_Z May I ask if it is working for you in the console? Because if it does, I should consider reinstalling python.

Comment: No, that's not the case. Check the GitHub link, they have a fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Keras decides if it allows updating the progress bar using a function named sys.stdout.isatty() which is false in PyCharm (despite it being able to update the progress bar), so all I had to do is to go into \Lib\site-packages\keras\utils and add `or "PYCHARM_HOSTED" in os.environ` to the `if` statement. (Line 355 for me, the pre-fix line was: `if self._dynamic_display:`)

Answer (score 0):

On PyCharm I found this solution pretty useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41598441

Run this code in the console

```
class PseudoTTY(object):
    def __init__(self, underlying):
        self.__underlying = underlying
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.__underlying, name)
    def isatty(self):
        return True

sys.stdout = PseudoTTY(sys.stdout)
```